# No value supplied for the SQL parameter when geting radio button parameter from JSP

Tags: jsp, radio-button

I'm trying to get values of a radio button in JSP. But I got this error.
When the radio button value is "All", the code run fine, but when it's another value, the issue appear. I printed the property and still got the value. I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

Error

```
    ERROR c.p.f.e.GlobalExceptionHandler - [URL] : http://localhost:8080/project/motsach/genre
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'theloai': This SqlParameterSource is empty
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:342) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:348) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:204) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at com.project.form.dao.BookDaoImpl.findBookbyGenre(BookDaoImpl.java:119) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.project.form.service.BookServiceImpl.findBookbyGenre(BookServiceImpl.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.findBookbyGenre(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.project.form.web.BookController.searchGenre(BookController.java:110) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

JSP

```
<form action="motsach/genre" modelAttribute="bookGenre" method="GET">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><spring:message code="label.genre" /></th>
                    <th><input type="radio" name="theloai" value="Horror">Horror</th>
                    <th><input type="radio" name="theloai" value="Fantasy">Fantasy</th>
                    <th><input type="radio" name="theloai" value="Comedy">Comedy</th>
                    <th><input type="radio" name="theloai" value="Romantic">Romantic</th>
                    <th><input type="radio" name="theloai" value="All">All</th>
                    <th><input type="submit" value="Find" /></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Controller.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "motsach/genre" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchGenre(Model model, @ModelAttribute("bookGenre") Book book, @RequestParam String theloai) {
        System.out.println(theloai);
        if (theloai.equals("All")) {
            model.addAttribute("books", bookService.findAll());
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("books", bookService.findBookbyGenre(theloai));
        }
        return "redirect:/motsach";
    }
```

DAOImplement
        public List findBookbyGenre(String theloai) {

```
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("theloai", theloai);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE theloai=:theloai";

        List<Book> result = null;
        try {
            result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BookMapper());
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            // do nothing, return null
        }
        return result;
    }

private static final class BookMapper implements RowMapper<Book> {
        public Book mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.setBook_ID(rs.getInt("id"));
            book.setTensach(rs.getString("tensach"));
            book.setTacgia(rs.getString("tacgia"));
            book.setTheloai(rs.getString("theloai"));
            book.setTinhtrang(rs.getString("tinhtrang"));
            book.setImage(rs.getBytes("image"));
            book.setImage_name(rs.getString("image_name"));
            return book;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issues and it was basically because the parameter mapping didn't like the spaces in the sql string.  I fixed it by replacing spaces around the equal sign.

Changing this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE theloai=:theloai";
```

To

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE theloai = :theloai";
```